# Como alterar a pasta no plugin jQuery File Upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Como alterar a pasta onde o plugin jQuery File Upload busca as imagens a serem exibidas?

Atualmente a pasta é a "files" porém não encontrei o local onde ele está indicando a pasta a ser buscada as imagens.

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que encontrei na net, tens 3 formas de fazer isso:

**1- Incluir no form**

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/Backload/UploadHandler" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ...
        <input type="hidden" name="objectContext" value="user123" />
        ...
    </form>
```

**2- Via Jquery**

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    // The example input, doesn't have to be part of the upload form:
    var $context = $('#objContext');
    data.formData = { example: $context.val() };
});
```

**3- No controller**

```
var fileUploadUrl = "/Backload/UploadHandler" + "?objectContext=user123";
```

Fonte: [Link Fonte](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/wiki/Example-06)

Comment: nestas formas que você enviou são para o local onde as imagens serão inseridas? ou o local de onde ele faz o carregamento?

Comment: Pois o meu problema é o seguinte: eu utilizo o sistema para upload de imagens de imóvel, onde cada imóvel tem sua pasta de imagens e necessito que ao editar o imóvel já seja aberto as imagens que já foram inseridas nele entende

Comment: Para o local onde são inseridas. No teu caso podes sempre construir a directoria a partir do imóvel. Estas a usar que linguagem de programação?

Comment: O local onde está sendo inserida as imagens está ok, ao cadastrar o imóvel já está indo para a pasta referente ao imovel, o problema é na hora de editar que preciso que busque as imagens dentro da pasta do imóvel pois por padrão do plugin é a pasta files que fica dentro do próprio plugin e não encontro onde faz esta referencia.

Comment: Ahh já estou a entender. Quando tu carregas as fotos para editar é que ele vai buscar à pasta files... Vou fazer umas pesquisas a ver se encontro alguma coisa :)

Comment: Exato, é na hora do editar que ele deve buscar de outra pasta, caso consiga alguma coisa e puder postar aqui eu seria muito grato